# Will this getter make a database call every time it's referenced?

Tags: c#, properties, getter

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
...    
    public List<SomeClass> MyProperty {
        get { 
            SomeClass.GetCollectionOfThese(someId);
        } 
    }
...
}
```

`GetCollectionOfThese()` calls the database to retrieve the records necessary to build the collection. Now let's say I have the following code somewhere else:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(someId);
List<SomeClass> temp = obj.MyProperty;

...

SomeClass otherObj = obj.MyProperty.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Foo == "bar");
```

In this case, is the database being called two times? Or is the property value cached in memory?

Comment: Did you run the code? What happened? Either way, that's your answer. When you have a question that is not answerable simply by running the code in the question, please post it. For example, say you wanted to *change* the behavior or *fix* it. But you do not need us to tell you what your code does, *running it* should do that.

Comment: well that's the problem, i wasn't sure. which is why i asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implemenation will result in multiple database calls. You've got to do the caching, if that's what you need. Something like:

```
public class MyClass {
...    

    private List<SomeClass> _myProperty = null;
    public List<SomeClass> MyProperty {
        get { 
            if (_myProperty == null) _myProperty = SomeClass.GetCollectionOfThese(someId);
            return _myProperty;
        } 
    }
...
}
```

Of course, then you're probably going to want to give clients a way to refresh the cache.

Comment: A more succinct way of writing that getter would be `return _myProperty ?? (_myProperty = SomeClass.GetCollectionOfThese(someId))`

Comment: ah yes, any chance to use null coalesce i'll take it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the technology that you use in your datalayer.
For example if you use Linq2Sql with single DataContext,  DataContext would cache entities for you and requery it from cache, so that you hit the DataBase only once. But that's not a typical scheme.